# Is it possible to have a multilingual site creating a subdirectory without the use of a plugin?

Tags: multi-language

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand whether it's possible to have a multilingual website on wordpress without a plugin, I want to add an english version to my site and what I thought of is creating a subdirectory in my cpanel, installing there an english version of wordpress and the theme builder I use, then creating there all the pages in english (while setting a password to prevent indexing while I'm still working on it). I'm not sure though if there is a way to correctly implement hreflangs after finishing up all the pages and if this would be a correct process in general. Has anyone maybe gone through the same issue? Thanks a lot

Comment: have you looked into multisites? You don't need separate installs, one WordPress install can serve multiple sites in subdirectories or subdomains

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I looked into it on an article, I was a little concerned about the fact that I have to choose subdomains (since my wordpress site has been online already for a few years) and then switch to subdirectories... is it a risky thing to do? I've read there are risks regarding link conflict but I'm not sure what exactly they refer to if in the new subdirectory there are no pages yet...

Comment: I am particularly interested in using a subdirectory so that my website ranking can benefit from both original and english version

Comment: I have no idea what you're referring to with link conflict, I've dealt with hundreds of multisites and this is the first I've seen it referenced. Multisites can also serve on completely different domains. Is there a reason you're asking how to do this without a plugin? There are lots of free multilingual plugins that work in many ways and it's much much easier than doing it from scratch and trying to figure out things. What you are asking about will require code to be written and a lot of manual processes and setup that a plugin is meant to take care of

Comment: I'd also avoid asking about the risks of switching between subdomains and sub directories here as that's not what your question asked, keep things to the specific question you asked, you can always create new questions if you have other queries. The site will flag this if we try to chat/have a discussion in the comments, the goal is to get an answer for the original question below that you can mark as the correct answer

Comment: I understand, didn't mean to go off topic, thanks anyway for your suggestions!

Comment: You don't have to use subdomains, you can use multi-site with subdirectories:  https://wetopi.com/how-to-setup-wordpress-multisite-with-subdirectories/